# why am I getting "Unable to resolve non-existing file" when running javascript - the file exists

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I get an error when running a javascript program in VSC (version 1.51.1 win10)

In the debugger page I get

> ```
>     /c/Users/yonatanlehman/Documents/apigen/tools
> ```
>
> file:///c:/Users/yonatanlehman/Documents/apigen/tools/src/methoddef.js:10

and when I click on the link to the file I get a dialog with

> ```
> Unable to open 'methoddef.js:10': Unable to read file 'c:\Users\yonatanlehman\Documents\apigen\tools\src\methoddef.js:10'
> ```
>
> (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file
> 'c:\Users\yonatanlehman\Documents\apigen\tools\src\methoddef.js:10').

But the filepath is correct!

This started out of the blue - not sure what changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try closing and reopening the project

Comment: This isn't work. It is like if car isn't started then exit and enter again